# How do I run a persistent background process as a non-privileged user in OS X?

Tags: macos, mac

I'm currently launching the process using `nohup` but occasionally after logging out and back in again the process is gone. Something is reaping it.

I don't need it to survive a reboot (so I think `launchd` might be overkill here), but I would like it to persist as long as the machine is up and running, whether I'm logged in or not.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Lingon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/files/). It is a very easy to use GUI with which you can edit and create launchd configuration files.

Comment: This makes the barrier to launchd entry low enough to use for this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`screen`? You can log out, and the screen sessions continue running. Although they shouldn't count on your FileVault home directory being mounted, if you use that feature.